# Deploying scrapy project on heroku

Tags: python-2.7, heroku, scrapy, scrapyd

I have a scrapy spider project which scraps some website an fetches me the data on it. My spider yields two JSON files in which all the data is that is scraped is stored.

Now, I have a flask web service which uses this above said two JSON files to satisfy the users request.

I have deployed this flask web service over heroku and works fine.

My problem here is I run the scrapy spider everyday on my local machine and then update the two JSON files on heroku manually.

I want to automate this process that is scrapy project should run everyday and the JSON files yielded should be updated automatically.

What solution I found here is if scrapy spider and web service are deployed as single project it will work as I want....but I am not sure if it can be done.

I have searched for topics about deploying scrapy project and I found scrapyd and even scrapy-heroku but I am clueless about how will they help or how should I use them to satisfy my specific requirement.

Answer (score 3):

I've been in a similar situation before.

Here's what you'll want to do: instead of using Scrapy to generate JSON files locally with the scraped data -- create a [Scrapy pipeline](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) and store your scraped data into a database instead ([Heroku Postgres](https://www.heroku.com/postgres), or something similar).

Then, when you run Scrapy, it'll scrape your site(s), and store the information into Postgres.

Now, you should have your Flask project deployed separately on Heroku. Instead of having it read from local JSON files, have it use [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/) to interact with the scraped data via your Heroku Postgres database.

Does that make sense?

This is usually the best way to handle scraping stuff -- the default Scrapy JSON item pipeline is great for testing, but usually not what you want for serious data.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok I get what you are saying...but still in this case also I will have to initiate the scrapy spider locally right..? I want something which will schedule the scraping job automatically on daily basis...hope you get me... and do you have any tutorial or example which will shed more light on what you have suggested in your answer....I feel your answer might solve half of my problem only if I figure out how to do it practically...as I totally agree on the theory you have mentioned...

Comment: Ah, gotcha! Scrapy actually has a scrapyd service you can run on a server: http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ This is the best way to run a spider every-so-often :) Does that answer your question?

Comment: I have run my scrapy spider on scrapyd server but still I have to fire scrapyd command from my local machine when I have to do that....I want to automate the process of initiating scrapy spider....that is when I once upload my scrapy spider on server and start it for the first time it should schedule itself and run everyday by itself at specified time

Comment: Ah ok. The way I do that with my projects is I have a cron script that uses the scrapyd API to start running the spiders every day. That's the best way I've found to do it :(

Comment: Yes even I figured out that way ...but still for that my local machine needs to be on that it will still depend on local machine to initiate.... right.?

Comment: Can you guide me to what solution you have given in your answer ...that is storing scraped data in heroku db and then accessing it in flask service deployed on heroku..?

Comment: Yah -- so the idea is that you have a dedicated server that runs scrapyd (an EC2 instance, or something similar). This server should be hosted somewhere in the cloud where it won't go down easily. This server should do two things: a) run scrapyd, b) run a cron job that tells scrapyd to run the scraper ever day (or week or whatever), c) have a scrapy item pipeline which takes items you scrape (with JSON) and POSTs them to your Heroku web service (Flask), which then stores the JSON data in a Heroku database.

Comment: ok....using amazon ec2 seems to be my choice here....but I am totally clueless about it....and need to perform this task in very less time....can you practically guide me through it....like by providing some tutorials...that will be of great help....

Comment: and yes I suppose ec2 is nothing but virtual machine similar to my local machine....that is I can configure it that way..? right..? ell me if I am wrong....locally I have everything me like a cron script which schedules my scrapy crawler....I just need to run all this scripts on ec2..? thats it right..?

Comment: I will try to do with a) and b) parts from your comments but will need help in doing c) part....will let you know about my progress... thank you very much///